# How to add a RecyclerView in a fragment Kotlin- I initialize the dataset but idk what to to with context

Tags: android, kotlin

ItemAdapter:

class ItemAdapter( val context: Context,  val dataset: List) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

Fragment:

val dataset: List =ArrayList()
val context: Context =

//so i can initialize the->    adapter= ItemAdapter(context, dataset)

Comment: Just FYI you probably don't need to pass in a `Context` - check out this example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter The place you definitely need one is in `onCreateViewHolder` to inflate your layout, and they're getting it from the `ViewGroup` that's passed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a context in `fragment` using `requireContext()`. It will be a context of Activity running current fragment

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a context, if you need it later you can get it from some view.

If required, you can use requireContext(), but if you remove the fragment when it's creating the adapter, the app will crash, because you'd be requiring a context you don't have.